# SonarQube 6 - Code Coverage with separate Jenkins Test Job

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage

Ist it possible to handle code coverage separate from other SonarQube analyses with Jenkins 2.73 and Sonar 6.7?

We have the following structure:

- Jenkins job A: Maven project A (nightly, SonarScanner)
- Jenkins job B: Maven project B (nightly, SonarScanner)
- Jenkins job T: Maven project with test / coverage of A + B (continuously)

Job A and B are special Sonar jobs running at night. Job T ist running all over the day for tests and coverage. We use the maven sonar scanner in job A and B but also would like to provide coverage by job T. Ist this possible?

As a workaround we save the coverage of continuously running job T at master for Job T and copy the jacoco.exec to the build client at runtime of nightly job A and B.

Ist there a better way to do this?